# Accessing nested elements with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following html:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
    <!-- START FILER DIV -->
    <div style="margin: 15px 0 10px 0; padding: 3px; overflow: hidden; background-color: #BCD6F8;">
    <div class="mailer">Mailing Address
        <span class="mailerAddress">500 ORACLE PARKWAY</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">MAIL STOP 5 OP 7</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">REDWOOD CITY CA 94065</span>
     </div>
```

I am trying to access "500 ORACLE PARKWAY" and "MAIL STOP 5 OP &", but I cannot find a way to do it. My attempt was this:

```
for item in soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "mailerAddress"}):
    if item.parent.name == 'div':
        return_list.append(item.contents)
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that there are elements after that in the html that use similar tags so it captures all of those when I just want the first two.

Edit: link: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=orcl

Comment: what kind of error are you encountering? I tried your code and I can see that you are able to retrieve the text within each span element.

Comment: Can you post the link of the HTML code?

Comment: Why would you try and interpret the HTML when there is a perfectly good XML document on that page you gave the link to: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;CIK=0001341439&amp;CIK=0001341439&amp;type=&amp;dateb=&amp;owner=include&amp;start=0&amp;count=40&amp;output=atom. Beautiful Soup should only ever be the last possible option.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only allowed to use this html and not the XML hah.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=orcl").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'lxml')
for item in soup.find_all(class_="mailerAddress")[:2]:
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
500 ORACLE PARKWAY
MAIL STOP 5 OP 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer this with the little bit of information we have. If you just want the first two elements of a certain class on a webpage you can use slicing.

```
soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "mailerAddress"})[0:2]
```